# Issue with libmemcached version upgrade

Tags: php, memcached, amazon-linux-2, libmemcache

I am trying to upgrade Libmemcached on my amazon linux2 server. Even after installing the latest version, I am still facing error as:

> Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: using touch command with binary protocol is not recommended with libmemcached versions below 1.0.18, please use ascii protocol or upgrade libmemcached in Unknown on line 0\n'

I am not able to trace the actual file path from where the old version is still been read. I have removed all the old memcached and libmemcached and re installed it with the latest versions. Still its not getting upgraded.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This is probably better suited to https://serverfault.com/. Id also recommend adding more details like the actual commands you're using and the responses/errors you get from them

Comment: Hi Wesley ,I am using below commands to update the Libmemcached:
wget https://launchpad.net/libmemcached/1.0/1.0.18/+download/libmemcached-1.0.18.tar.gz
tar xvf libmemcached-1.0.18.tar.gz
cd libmemcached-1.0.18
./configure
make && make install

Comment: but on apply yum info libmemcached , it still shows older version

Comment: The package manager does not know that you upgraded libmemcached from source.

Answer (score 0):

`php-memcached` seems to use the version number from the libmemcached headers, so it only knows with which libmemcached version it was compiled and initially linked with, while calling `memcached_lib_version()` at runtime would reveal the currently, dynamically, linked libmemcached version in use.

You'd have to rebuild `php-memcached` against the upgraded libmemcached, so it picks up the new version from its headers.